# When does EntityManager commit?

Tags: jpa, jersey, ejb-3.1, entitymanager

I have the following service...

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class RandomService {

    @EJB RandomString stringTokenizer;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public String generate(Actions action)
    {
        Token token = new Token();
        token.setAction(action);
        token.setExpiry(new Date());
        token.setToken(stringTokenizer.randomize());

        em.persist(token);
        //em.flush();

        return String.format("%010d", token.getId()) + token.getToken();
    }
}
```

If I do not put em.flush() then the line token.getId() will return null (Using DB GENERATED SEQUENCE) though I know if I return Token instead of string to the calling service the id is set. So it seems that EM flushes when the service returns a token object but not when I put String. By putting flush I get what I need is that right though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not confuse flushing with committing. During `flush()` JPA provider physically sends generated SQL to the database and, in your case, reads the generated ID and populates it in the bean. <strike>Note that you should always use the returned entity rather than the original one passed to `persist()`:</strike>

```
token = em.persist(token);
```

Committing, on the other hand, performs database commit. Obviously it will trigger `flush()` first, but it won't help you here. But since you are asking - every method in EJB is transactional by default. This means the transaction is committed when you leave the first EJB on the stack: if you call one EJB from another, the callee joins the caller transaction by default (see: *transaction propagation behaviour*).

Also note that the rules when to `flush()` are a bit complicated since every provider tries to do this as late as possible and in batches.

Comment: I can't seem to do token = em.persist(token); Using Netbeans 7.0.1 I guess this is only in latest EJB?

Comment: My bad, it is the `merge()` that returns the new instance, not `persist()`. Nevertheless, you need to `flush()` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. So whats your though on the above code should I do the formatting in place or at higher level in the caller?